# New Relic not collecting data from Play 2.2.1 Scala App

Tags: playframework, newrelic, playframework-2.2, javaagents

I'm trying to use `New Relic's Java Agent 3.1.0` to monitor a Scala based `Play 2.2.1` web app, however the NR Web UI doesn't seem to be collecting any data from my server.

I've verified that my `newrelic.yml` config file is correct, and the Agent appears to hook in as expected when launching the app using the following command (as per the official instructions [found here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/play-installation-for-java#prod-mode-22)):

```
root@myserver:/var/www/myapp/target/universal/myapp# ./bin/myapp -J-javaagent:/var/www/myapp/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.bootstrap_classpath=true

Nov 4, 2013 18:15:41 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent is using Logback
Nov 4, 2013 18:15:41 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Loading configuration file "/var/www/myapp/newrelic/./newrelic.yml"
Play server process ID is 11599
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

After running the above, I can see the name of my app show up within the Applications section of NR's Web UI, so my app is certainly pinging the service, however I don't see any actual data within the dashboards.

My `newrelic_agent.log` file is as follows:

```
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:20 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Writing to New Relic log file: /var/www/myapp/newrelic/logs/newrelic_agent.log
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:20 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent Host: myserver IP: <snipped - it had my IP here!>
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:24 +1100 NewRelic 1 ERROR: com/caucho/vfs/WriteStream is marked as a weaved class, but no methods are matched to be weaved.
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:36 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Configured to connect to New Relic at collector.newrelic.com:443
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:36 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Setting audit_mode to false
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:36 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Setting protocol to "https"
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:37 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Configuration file is /var/www/myapp/newrelic/./newrelic.yml
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:37 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: New Relic Agent v3.1.0 has started
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:37 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Java version: 1.7.0_45
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:37 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: The newrelic.bootstrap_classpath system property is deprecated.
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:37 +1100 NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent class loader is null which typically means the agent is loaded by the bootstrap class loader.
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:44 +1100 NewRelic 9 INFO: Collector redirection to collector-9.newrelic.com:443
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:45 +1100 NewRelic 9 INFO: Agent run id: 404659456
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:45 +1100 NewRelic 9 INFO: Agent 11288@myserver/My App connected to collector.newrelic.com:443
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:45 +1100 NewRelic 9 INFO: Real user monitoring is enabled with auto instrumentation for application "My App"
Nov 4, 2013 17:39:45 +1100 NewRelic 9 INFO: Errors will be sent to New Relic for Mealdrum
```

Can anybody offer any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue using Play 2.2.1 and the NewRelic Agent 3.3.1 - did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @Sjaak not as yet. They told me they would escalate the issue to their Engineering Dept but I have yet to hear back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By working directly in a support ticket, we discovered yet another possible issue with play 2.2 and New Relic's instrumentation and we will be fixing that by releasing version 3.2 of our Java agent. It should be out shortly after December 2nd, 2013, and will show up on the [release notes page.](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/java)

Comment: Thanks mate! I can confirm that `v3.2.1` of the Java Agent resolved my issue. Highly appreciate your team's stellar level of support. :)

Answer (score 3):

While this log shows a clean agent startup, it's possible that you're the victim of an issue with the 3.1.0 agent that interfered with New Relic's instrumentation of Play 2 apps. Java Agent 3.1.1 resolves this. Release notes are on the docs site: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/java

I recently noticed there are no update instructions anywhere on our docs site but it's dead easy: replace your newrelic.jar and nothing else and restart your JVM.

After you've got 3.1.1 installed and your JVM restarted, metrics should report correctly. If not, I'd open a ticket at support.newrelic.com so we can takea  look at detailed logs.

Comment: Thanks Toby. I updated to v3.1.1, but unfortunately I am still not seeing any data come through in NR's Web UI. Looks like there may still be some issues with the Java Agent's compatibility with Play 2, so I have opened a support ticket as suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I went so far as to verify that other users are instrumenting successfully with play 2.2.1, but I'll work with you in a ticket to work out what's going on here. Talk to you soon.